# Implementing BindingAdapter outside of class which that extended from BaseObservable

Tags: android, android-databinding

im my `User` class i have one `BindingAdapter` which that names `loadImage` and that work fine

```
class User : BaseObservable() {
    var username: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    var profilePicUrl: String? = null

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("android:profilePicUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(view)
        }
    }
}
```

now, as i have more functions like with that i want to use them on other class for example:

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:profilePicUrl")
    fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(view)
    }
}
```

> my problem is i can't use this class as `BindingAdapters` on `Activity` or this activity ViewModel such as `User`

my `LoginActivity` class:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoginResultCallbacks {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: LoginActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity)
        binding.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginViewModelFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    }

    ...
}
```

`LoginViewModel` class:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private User user;
    private LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks;

    public LoginViewModel(LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks) {
        this.loginResultCallbacks = loginResultCallbacks;
        this.user = new User();
    }
}
```

`LoginViewModelFactory` class

```
public class LoginViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
    private LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks;

    public LoginViewModelFactory(LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks) {
        this.loginResultCallbacks = loginResultCallbacks;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new LoginViewModel(loginResultCallbacks);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best way for adding binding adapter that adding you adapter in class like what you do and then the only thing that you must do is your model extend that class

```
class BindingAdapters : ViewModel () {
    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("android:profilePicUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(view)
        }
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel extends BindingAdapters {
    private User user;
    private LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks;

    public LoginViewModel(LoginResultCallbacks loginResultCallbacks) {
        this.loginResultCallbacks = loginResultCallbacks;
        this.user = new User();
    }
}
```

so every model that extend `BindingAdapters` can use `profilePicUrl` adapter